# Trying to calculate a sum from input, when text is thrown in as well

Tags: java

Have input passed through Scanner. It has both numbers and letters and spaces.

Letters being stripped out, leaving only spaces and numbers.

If I input without spaces, it works fine, but if I add spaces, it throws the error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" (in
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException)

This is applied against the line

int dataInt = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);

> Stderr outputs
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   Program2.main(Program2.java:21)

Code is below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = kb.nextLine();
    input = input.replaceAll("[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]","");
    System.out.println(input);
    while(!input.equals("#")){
        String[] data = input.split(" ");
        int sum = 0;
        if (!input.equals("")){
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                int dataInt = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
                sum = sum + dataInt;

            }

        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        input = kb.nextLine();
    }
} //main


} // class Program2
```

Comment: Split on `"\\s+"`, or call `data[i].trim()` before applying `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: psst: `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]` == `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: Regex's kill me. Thx @Pshemo

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Tried both those, didn't fix it.

Comment: Appreciate the downvotes, but could anyone please explain what they are downvoting for? I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm guessing it's 'cause you didn't specify what your inputs should look like, and what you're expecting for output. It would help if you pointed out exactly which lines produce those exceptions as well.

Comment: @Alex As mentioned, it's the line 
    int dataInt = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` means you're trying to convert an empty string into a number, and it failed 'cause empty strings aren't numbers. You have to deal with that case somehow. Easiest way I can think of ATM is to check if the string is empty, and skip it if it is, but I don't know what the rest of your requirements are

Comment: @Alex yeah, that makes sense, except the input isn't empty. It contains a mix of spaces(which the split() works with), text and numbers.

Comment: @hggohh You need to be more specific. What line? What does that mean? Are you expecting `12 34 2 3 4 1 5 2`, or `1 \n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n 5`, or something else entirely? You need to be specific about these things. 'Cause if you can't put your requirements into words, it'll be much harder for you to put it in terms of logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120378/discussion-between-hgg-ohh-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this program is supposed to extract all numbers in each line, and sum them up. Each line is free to be mixed with characters and spaces. Ex: `fsdjs 3 8 herlks 983` should produce 994.

There were a few things wrong

```
if (!input.equals(""))
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
```

will only check if the input is empty, but it should be the array of split up substrings that we should be worried about as that's what we should be operating on. There will be empty strings after calling `split()`. It should really be

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (!data[i].equals(""))
```

While running your code, there seems to be times where the program gets caught up with spaces while calling `parseInt()`. Not sure how it worked, but it had to do with the number of `replaceAll()`s.

The string input is basically a list of numbers delimited by a series of alphabets and spaces. You could just split on that with `input.split("[^\\d]+)` instead of calling `replaceAll()` multiple times.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);

        while(!input.equals("#")) {
            //                    VVV
            String[] data = input.split("[^\\d]+");
            int sum = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (!data[i].equals("")) {
                    int dataInt = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
                    sum = sum + dataInt;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(sum);
            input = kb.nextLine();
        }
    } //main
} // class Program2
```